# Longest substring without repeating character(Leetcode)

Tags: java, algorithm

I found a lot of solutions for this but I am just trying to understand why my code doesn't work. Basically I've taken two arrays. In one I added all characters until I found repetition. If a character repeats I converted all elements in the array to string, found their length and send it to another arrays. Lastly I sorted the second array and printed the largest length.

```
    public int lengthOfLongestSubstring(String s) {
        char a[]=new char[s.length()];
        int b[]=new int[s.length()];
        StringBuilder sbf = new StringBuilder("");
        for(int x=0;x<s.length();x++){
            char c=s.charAt(x);
            if (new String(a).indexOf(c) == -1) {
                sbf.append(a);
                b[x]=sbf.length();
                sbf=null;
            }
            else
            {
                a[x]=c;
            }
        }
        Arrays.sort(b);
        return b[(b.length)-1];
    }
}
```

This was my error message

```
WARNING: A command line option has enabled the Security Manager
WARNING: The Security Manager is deprecated and will be removed in a future release

java.lang.NullPointerException: 
Cannot invoke "java.lang.StringBuilder.append(char[])" 
because 
"<local4>" is null 
at line 10, Solution.lengthOfLongestSubstring 
at line 54, __DriverSolution__.__helper__ 
at line 84, __Driver__.main
```

[The link for the problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-substring-without-repeating-characters/)

Comment: After the first iteration, your `StringBuilder` will be `null`. And at the second step of iteration you'll get an exception.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting `sbf` to `null` and then trying to call a method on it on the next iteration. You should set its length to 0 to reset it instead:

```
sbf.setLength(0);
```

You also want to change the condition of your loop to:

```
if (new String(a).indexOf(c) != -1)
```

---

Edit: The `a` array is supposed to hold the current substring, but it looks like you aren't clearing it when a duplicate is found. Fortunately you don't need the `a` string. `sbf` can hold the current substring.

Here's the updated version:

```
public static int lengthOfLongestSubstring(String s) {
  int maxLength = 0;
  StringBuilder sbf = new StringBuilder();
  for (int x = 0; x < s.length(); x++) {
    char c = s.charAt(x);
    sbf.delete(0, sbf.indexOf(Character.toString(c)) + 1);
    sbf.append(c);
    maxLength = Math.max(maxLength, sbf.length());
  }
  return maxLength;
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
  System.out.println(lengthOfLongestSubstring("abcdefa")); // 6
}
```

Other optimizations you can make are:

- Look up the sliding window technique. This makes it so that you don't need to store a substring. You can use a hash table to count duplicates instead of looking through the substring every time.

Comment: That will prevent NPE, but with that fix alone the solution remains to be broken.  The condition inside the loop is always `true` and array `a` never gets populated.

Comment: I made the following changes and changed it from sbf=null to sbf.setLength(0), now i am getting wrong answer

Comment: @Lostmymind See the update.

Comment: @DavidG what i don't understand in the above code is, how are you adding the elements which are repeating? like if the input is "pwwkewh", here the longest substring is wke but the above code only adds "ke" hence returns 2 instead of 3.
So i added a **sbf.append(c);** in the yes part of the if block. but i am still getting stuck later, like if the input is "au"

Comment: @Lostmymind You're right! We need to delete the current string inside `sbf` and then add the character `c`.

Comment: @Lostmymind See my latest update. I think that works.

Comment: @DavidG, i tried running its, still gets stuck when input is **AU**, i think u know why, so we only enter elements in **b** when we find a duplicate element, if we don't find it b remains empty, i guess that's why its failing. Just saw your update, sorry going through it rn

Comment: @Lostmymind My latest update works with `"au"`.

Comment: @DavidG  This method is just amazing, i totally got it, but i don't understand why it failed for **dvdf**. when i am dry running it in my head its working... :/

Comment: @Lostmymind Okay I think this last one works.

Answer (score 0):

I don't comment your logic but just point out the mistake.

Let's say this lines execute

```
if (new String(a).indexOf(c) == -1) {
            sbf.append(a);
            b[x]=sbf.length();
            sbf=null;
        }
```

After that, StringBuilder `sbf` is null and next time when it tries to append it fails because it is already null.

Comment: I made the following changes and changed it from sbf=null to sbf.setLength(0), now i am getting wrong answer